# How to use grease pencil to animate embroidery?

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, grease-pencil

So, [this official Blender demo file](https://download.blender.org/demo/geometry-nodes/geometry_nodes_sample_uv_surface.blend) has a system of geometry nodes that takes a curve and turns it into 3d embroidery stitching. My question is, can I somehow use a grease pencil drawing/animation as the input instead of just a curve? I'm trying to animate the face of a plushy. It's all black lines, if that makes it easier.

I know I can permanently convert grease pencil to curve, but that's not what I want: It needs to be animated.

Answer (score -1):

I Fix this problem.
**you want to drawing/animation Right**

[this official Blender demo file modify with animated](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/br3molf19mv38600hjm30/geometry_nodes_sample_uv_surface.blend?rlkey=w75nzqks5ycx37g8qihoz263a&dl=0)

**explanation** -->
I first calculated the geometry from the Realize Instances node and then resampled the curve using length mode in the Resample Curve node. Later we deleted the curve points using the Delete Geometry node. Converted the animation to a draw effect using the Delete Geometry node selection input. Played the animation in all frames using Greater Than and Index and Scene Time in Compare node and controlled the speed from Multiply node.
[image]

**How to Use** --> resample length value is increase geometry and Multiply node value control Animation speed and i join both value in group input node

**and you want grease pencil to animate embroidery**

like this animation [youtube link](https://youtu.be/GuSr4LZ8c-o)

similer animation - my animation in add animation follow by curve

i hope solved your problem

Comment: Please explain at least briefly what process you used to solve the problem. Users shouldn't have to download a file and explore it to try to understand how you managed to bring a solution.

Comment: You did not pay attention to the question. I don't want the embroidery to be drawn into place progressively, I want to use an *animated Grease Pencil* drawing as the input.

Comment: You Want like this effect [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/54ya1km1og646gx8w75g3/honey_logo-video0001-0302.mp4?rlkey=k879ol4m2jhwl8mjtvkz9c753&dl=0)

Comment: @SuhelMansuri No, I do not. It's for the face of a character that is alive and moving, but meant to be a plushie, so I want a grease pencil animation, not a static drawing, to be live translated into embroidery marks on the face. Are you not familiar with grease pencil 2D animations? I don't want it to look like it's being drawn/sewn into place, I want it to look like the embroidered face is alive.

Comment: try to drawn grease pencil 2d animation per frame. This work is not possible for me. I am disabled so my hands are not stable, sorry [YouTube Link](https://youtu.be/umgPXCmYmzY)